# How can I get data using jQuery from golang code (server)?

Tags: javascript, go

Users will submit data using the text editor given on the website. My golang server will capture it , process it and then display result below the text editor on the website.

I am able to get the user input and process it, but I'm unable to send it back to website for displaying results.

main function:

```
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./codemirror")))
    http.HandleFunc("/getRules", getRules)
...
```

getRules function:

```
//capture form data
//do some processing on captured data
    js, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>nvrule playground</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/codemirror/theme/the-matrix.css">
        <style>
        .button {
          padding: 15px 25px;
          font-size: 24px;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
          outline: none;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 15px;
          box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        }

        .button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

        .button:active {
          background-color: #3e8e41;
          box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
          transform: translateY(4px);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe name="hiddenFrame" width="0" height="0" border="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>

        <form action="/getRules" method="post" id="ruleForm" target="hiddenFrame">
            <textarea id="codemirror-textarea" name="rule"></textarea>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

default.js:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codemirror-textarea"), {
    lineNumbers : true,
    theme : "the-matrix",
    value: "Enter rules here"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can use ajax.

```
$('#ruleForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: form.serialize(),
                   success: function(json){
                   console.log(json)
                   var templateHtml = $('#resultsArea').html(),
                   template = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
                   $('#ajaxResponse').html(template(json));
            }
        });

    });
```

useful link:[stackoverflow (question contains my answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685254/display-json-response-in-another-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an endpoint to get the status of the processing that you can poll using `setTimeout`, something like:

```
 /rule/:id/status
```

It can return a status code such as (apart of the typical 404, 500, etc.):

```
{ status: "processing | idle | finished" }
```

Once the status is `finished` then GET the result.

```
/rule/:id
```

Hope it helps.